# Adding another table in Database android

Tags: android, sqlite

Can i use this way to add another table in my database? See my onupgrade i tried this way is it possible. and one thing is database upgraded everytime we Add or delete information.??

```
public class DataBaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE "+
        mDatabase.Tableinfo.Table_Name +"("
        +mDatabase.Tableinfo.Name+" TEXT,"
        +mDatabase.Tableinfo.phone+" INTEGER,"
        +mDatabase.Tableinfo.status+" TEXT,"
        +mDatabase.Tableinfo.Pic+" BLOB"+")";
private static final String Contacts_Table = "CREATE TABLE "+
        mDatabase.Tableinfo.contacts +"("
        +mDatabase.Tableinfo.Contacts_id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        +mDatabase.Tableinfo.Contacts_name+" TEXT,"
        +mDatabase.Tableinfo.Contacts_phone+" INTEGER,"
        +mDatabase.Tableinfo.status_contact+" TEXT,"
        +mDatabase.Tableinfo.Contact_pic+" BLOB"+")";

public DataBaseOperations(Context context) {
    super(context, mDatabase.Tableinfo.Database_Name, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if(newVersion==1){
    db.execSQL(Contacts_Table);
    onCreate(db);

  }
}
```

and this is my that contract class.

```
public class mDatabase {
public mDatabase(){
}
 public static abstract class Tableinfo{
 public static final String Name = "Name";
 public static final String status = "status";
 public static final String phone = "Phone";
 public static final String Pic  = "Pro_pic";
 public static final String Database_Name = "User_info.db";
 public static final String Table_Name = "User";
 public static final String contacts = "Contacts";
 public static final String Contacts_id= "Contact_id";
 public static final String Contacts_name = "Contacts name";
 public static final String Contacts_phone = "Contacts phone No";
 public static final String status_contact = "Status";
 public static final String Contact_pic = "pic";
}
}
```

Comment: onUpgrade is called when you upgrade your database. It is best you put all your create table statement in onCreate cause it called when the database is created first time and your heading says mysql change that to sqlite

Comment: but it doesn't create the 2nd table on onCreate(); . It only creates the first one.

Comment: You have no code that creates a second table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Your `onUpgrade` simply calls

```
db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
```

then redirects to

```
onCreate(db);
```

where it calls the same thing again.

Look at this answer. It gives a better way to handle upgrades.

[Upgrade database on deployed Android app on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646496/upgrade-database-on-deployed-android-app-on-update/33646675#33646675)

As a clarification. `onCreate` is ONLY called when the database does not exist.

`onUpgrade` is called IF the database exists AND the existing database version number is lower than the version number you use in the constructor of the OpenHelper.

If the database xists and the version numbers are the same, NEITHER is called.

Comment: please look at the Question again. It was a mistake

Comment: It still wont work. You are redirecting to OnCreate from your onUpgrade. Use onCreate to CREATE your database for the very first time.  Then use onUpgrade when the version number changes to UPGRADE your database. Again, read my answer to the question I linked which gives a simple way to handle upgrades.

Comment: If i add db.execSQL(Contatcs-) in onCreate; it should work right right coz it will redirect. right?

Comment: your oncreate already contains that. Please stop trying to redirect. It is not a good idea. read the extra data i appended to my answer. The documentation also contains everything you need. A real app will almost never want to redirect from onUpgrade to onCreate.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Comment: Thanks Dude. You are the best.